# Multiple click events inside one element

Tags: javascript

I have the following HMTL code:

```
<li>
    <img .../>
    <img .../>
    <img .../>
</li>
```

I want to register different functions for each element (one for the list item, and three other for the images). I registered click events on all but when I click the images, the li function triggers.

```
li.addEventListener("click",open,false);
img1.addEventListener("click",edit,false);
img2.addEventListener("click",delete,false);
img3.addEventListener("click",add,false);
```

I googled what happens when you set to true the last parameter but still no luck.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: RTFM: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

Also, `delete` is a javascript keyword and should _not_ be used.

Comment: I know @forivall, I just typed 4 random functions here to demonstrate. I didn't want to paste all the code I have so everyone could understand. Thanks for the tip anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define your functions, stop event from propagating like so:

```
function open(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
}

function edit(e) {
   e.stopPropagation()
}
```

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

expanding on designcise's answer... you need to use e.stopPropagation() to stop the event from bubbling up

```
$('li img').on('click',function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('img clicked');
});
```

here a jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/hbGRS/

Comment: @designcise I know the examples don't use jQuery, but the question *is* tagged jQuery. I'm not trying to defend this answer, I'm just saying

Comment: It's always good to show other ways to do it. A lot of people come here through search engines :)